# UINavigationController on top of a modal view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a modal view controller that I put onto screen using `presentModalViewController:animated`. This particular view controller, an instance of `UIViewController`, has a `UITableView` and cells with further `detailAccessory` options. Clicking on a date row should allow a controller with `UIDatePicker` to populate on the screen. The problem is this:

1. You cannot put two modal views onto screen at once.
2. Because of constraint #1, I have to use `UINavigationController` and `pushViewController:animated:`. What this does is push my controller with a `UIDatePicker` on top of the stack, but physically BELOW my modal view controller.

Does this imply that my modal view controller needs its own `UINavigationController`? What's the best bet to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly you are

1. presenting a modal view
2. responding to the cell did select message
3. pushing in a new view somewhere, probably with the navigation controller underneath your modal view

If you want to present a new UINavigationController modally, you can.  A good example of that is the People Picker.

I think it may be easier to just slide in a a UIDatePicker from the bottom on your modal view when the user performs the action.  That would eliminate the need to push in a new view controller, but you would need to resize the table view to accommodate the showing/hiding of the date picker.

Comment: Is People Picker a demo which Apple has written, hosted on their developer site?

Comment: The people picker is a built in picker like the Image Picker.  It's in the AddressBookUI framework